# Javascript: How to update track artwork in SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

just wondering how and where to put the artwork_data for the SoundCloud API update track function

```
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
      <script>
        SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
         redirect_uri: 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI'
       });

     // connect and update track data
      SC.connect(function() {
      SC.get('/tracks/13198684', function(track) {
      SC.put(track.permalink_url, { track: {
      description: 'This track was recorded in Berlin',
      genre: 'Electronic',
      artwork_data: '/path/to/image/to/upload'
     }});
  });
});
```

I'm not sure about the artwork_data above, I'm just taking a gander. If anybody has an idea, it would be very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dude! Use it as a reference: https://github.com/abitlog/react.js-voice-audio-player . In a brief, you have to manually change the url path to the image. This function might be helpful for you :

```
const url = require('url');

const formatCover = function (coverUri, size = 't300x300', format = '.png') {
    const { host, protocol, pathname, search } = url.parse(coverUri);

    return protocol + '//' + host + pathname.split('.')[0].split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-') + '-' + size + format + (search || '');
};
```